1990s simplistic rocket game
I used to visit the library in the 90s before we got a home computer. In the era of Minesweeper, there was a very simple 2d rocket launch game. I believe you had to connect coloured lines to make the rocket launch to build your score. The game was in a rectangular box, like the Minesweeper grid. Maybe a mouse featured. I can picture it clearly in my head but not the name. Anyone?

A warm welcome to SE/Retrocomputing! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and you might want to read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. -- Would you mind to [edit] your question to add a doodled image of the "picture [...] clearly in my mind", please?

Sure you don't mean "lander" where you have a small craft (like the Apollo eagle) to land on a flat surface but slow enough to not crash?
